# How to treat bad data for a date?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have this PHP code to convert a MMDDYY date into 'date' format for a MySQL TABLE:

```
$date = new DateTime($TRANSACTION_DATE_MMDDYY_raw);
TRANSACTION_DATE_MMDDYY = $date->format('Y/m/d') ;
```

The problem is, sometimes the data makes no sense. For example, this is failing on a date of '980671'. DateTime can't figure out what to do with it, and it looks like a bad data entry to me considering everything else is in the expect MMDDYY format.

How should I treat bad data like this? I thought about the options, I could just store it as-is but if it's wrong it seems like that it would cause other problems down the road. I could have it entered as empty or 0000-00-00. What's the best way to handle this? And no, I can't go back to someone to get this corrected it's from a state database. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know *all* the formats that your applications accepts? If not, then you should - for the most part...

Comment: If you have the option to not store the value I'd take it. You'll have no end of trouble querying bad values. You could also have a "raw" column for the data as-is and a "regular date" column for the data that converted successfully to a date.

Comment: If you get random inputs, then basically GIGO applies - garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Where do you get the date, is it a user inputting that data? if So you should put validation in place before it hits the PHP server

Comment: As I mentioned, "And no, I can't go back to someone to get this corrected it's from a state database. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What to do with the data depends entirely upon your organization's application.  We have no way of testing what the data will do to your system, so I recommend you enter junk / null data and attempt to work with it in your system.  You will see first-hand how the system treats it and you will get a better idea of what you can do to "fix" the bad data.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I'm not sure how you mean.  I did edit my answer, maybe you only saw the single-sentence version.

Comment: Yeah, now is clear. You're right, `980671` doesn't mean anything at all, can't do magic to extract a date from it. +1